# Using T-SQL to read an XML feed directly into an XML field in a table?

Tags: sql, xml, import

I see a LOT of resources about producing feeds from T-SQL2005, about parsing XML into a database schema, processing, bulk operations, etc.  What I don't see is how to have, for example, a statement/s in a stored proc or function which can simply access a URL for an XML feed, load the XML into a table field or sproc variable and close the connection.

I understand it might be necessary to use an external layer, like a C# web app, but it would be great (considering all the other complex functions T-SQL provides) to just read a feed or file directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OPENROWSET if the file is on the same server, example

```
CREATE TABLE XmlImportTest
(
        xml_data xml
)
GO

INSERT INTO XmlImportTest(xml_data)
SELECT  xmlData 
FROM
(
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\TestXml.xml' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
) AS FileImport (XMLDATA)
```

If you want to import all of them from a folder, take a look at [How to import a bunch of XML files from a directory in T-SQL](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-import-a-bunch-of-xml-files-from-)

If you need to acces it from a URL then SSIS could do it if it is a web service or perhaps even SQLCLR

Comment: ahh, missed the URL part, could be done with SSIS if it is a web service

Comment: Ah I didn't think of SSIS. Probably the best place to do that sort of stuff.

Comment: some info about the webservice task http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx

Comment: Btw, found this: "How to call a web service using the web service task" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952927(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inbuilt that I'm aware of. It would be possible to do this through the [Object Automation extended stored procedures](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx) but you would be better off using the CLR for this (if you have to do it within SQL Server at all - I feel an external app might be better).